# Как при помощи javascript сменить стиль?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как при помощи javascript изменить стиль?

```
<link id='style' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/load.css">
<script id='libraries' src="javascript/load.js"></script>
```

Comment: Саргей в ы хотите сказать что можно просто написать document.getElementById('load').style = "style/load1.css";
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('style').href = 'styles/newload.css';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById('style').setAttribute('href', 'styles/newload.css');
```

Comment: не забудьте, что JavaScript подгружается клиенту, Так что чем меньше кода, тем лучше.

Comment: Чем лучше то? Что время загрузки меньше? А Вы скорость измерьте. Я думаю разница ничтожна мала. А мой вариант Вам просто не понравился.